# Nombre de tabla en SELECT

Tags: php

quisiera saber como poner el nombre de una tabla recibida por POST en un SELECT. Estoy probando varias alternativas y no hay manera de que haga la búsqueda:

```
$response=mysql_query("select id,answer from ".$_POST['bd']." where id IN($order) 
    ORDER BY FIELD(id,$order)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP estás usando? ¿Por qué no usas mejor PDO? Tal y como lo tienes ahora mismo, tu código pide a gritos un SQL Inyection...

Comment: Perdona, no tengo mucha idea de PDO... voy a ver como lo podría solucionar.

Comment: @Vieira te dejo una entrada de cómo evitar inyección sql usando librerías php (PDO o Mysqli): http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero como ya te han dicho deberías usar PDO.
Deberías de usar consultas preparadas para que nadie pueda hacerte inyecciones sql, usando los parámetros sin filtrar que tienes como $_POST['bd'].

Aun así, yo lo primero que haría en tu caso seria cojer y mirar que valor te viene en $_POST['bd'] y hacerle un purify para quitarte etiquetas tales como  y según el valor que te venga, que podría ser por ejemplo numérico adjudicarle un valor.

Ejemplo:

```
if (intval($_POST['bd']) === 1) {
    $from = "db.answers";
}

$query=mysql_query("
    select 
        id,answer 
    from 
        {$from} 
    where 
        id IN($order) 
    ORDER BY 
        FIELD(id,$order)")   or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Funciona @UmbrellaSpirit. Muchísimas gracias. Tendré que empollar PDO...